# Error BLAZOR106 when saving Javascript/TypeScript file with the same component's name

Tags: javascript, typescript, blazor

I have a .Net6 Blazor Server Side project.

I created a component called `HomePage.razor`, another one called `HomePage.razor.cs` and a TypeScript file called `HomePage.razor.ts`. This way, I get a nice visual of the `HomePage.razor` in the solution explorer, as the "child" files nest in it.

When I save my TypeScript file, the file `wwwroot\Pages\HomePage.razor.js` is automatically generated, and I refer it at my `_Host.cshtml`.

Also, as soon as I save it, I get the error `BLAZOR106 - The JS module file 'c:\...\wwwroot\Pages\HomePage.razor.js' was defined but no associated razor component or view was found for it.`

If I change the name of my TypeScript file from `HomePage.razor.ts` to anything else - like `HomePage.ts` - save it, and delete the old generated JS file at `wwwroot`, everything works fine. But this way, I lose the nice "collapsing by name" in the solution explorer that VS2022 provides.

I couldn't find any content related to the `BLAZOR106` error (Google and Microsoft documentation), so I wonder if you know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file? If so, configure it to compile the TypeScript to a name that doesn't include `.razor` in it.

Comment: I have a `tsconfig.json` file, but I wonder if it is possible to configure it to rename the output files with a pattern. I think I'll have to write a msbuild task or use an additional `build` npm script.
This is not cool because I'll have to remove the TypeScript MsBuild and create mannually a custom npm script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error but in my case I wasn't even using a razor component, just a razor page .cshtml file. Similar to you, I also had a .cshtml.cs and .cshtml.js file because I like the organization of that.

```
Pages/Index.cshtml
Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
Pages/Index.cshtml.js
```

Originally I was using a bundleconfig.json to minify in place.

```
Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js
Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js.map
```

Then I used libman to copy the js files into:

```
wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.cshtml.js
wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js
wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js.map
```

As you can see, I was not using razor components or Blazor anywhere in my application. And this worked fine when targeting .NET 5

I upgraded to .NET 6 and I started getting the same error you are getting.

Background magic is going on here that the aspnet team should address but in the meantime my workaround was to remove the .cshtml. part from the file name in wwwroot.

```
wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.min.js
wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.min.js.map
```

To achieve this, I **changed my bundleconfig to output directly** to those files and I removed the libman part. It actually made more sense than what I was doing before because I only care that the original Index.cshtml.js file is nested.

```
bundleconfig.json
{
    "outputFileName": "Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Pages/Index.cshtml.js"
    ]
}

libman.json
{
  "provider": "filesystem",
  "library": "Pages/Index.cshtml.js",
  "files": [
    "Pages/Index.cshtml.js",
    "Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js",
    "Pages/Index.cshtml.min.js.map"
  ],
  "destination": "wwwroot/js/"
}
```

To just this:

```
bundleconfig.json
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/Pages/Index.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Pages/Index.cshtml.js"
    ]
}
```